# Spurious "install update" shield on my shutdown tab

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, windows-update, shutdown

Every now and then (and right now) I have that "install update shield" appearing on my shutdown tab, but when I go to shut down, it just shuts down as per normal, no updates installed. Then upon rebooting, it returns. As I recall it's never there RIGHT after restart (normal or not?) but appears again maybe after the full boot sequence finishes.

I have no pending (non-optional) updates and no recent failed updates and there have been periods of time when this does not happen so I assume I have no failed updates at all.

Any ideas?

To add confusion... this machine (win 7) has an mSATA drive that has linux installed while the main drive has win 7 installed. The mSATA is in dual boot mode so it will ask which OS while if the Win7 drive is first on the order it will just boot straight to Win 7 (duh).

Thing is I am not 100% if this intermittent shield thing happens only when win-7 is primary or not... I am win-7 primary now (legacy boot) and it is happening now.

Thanks in advance.

Mike